# Apply a function to a list of dataframes n list elements at a time

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataframe that contains a grouping variable.  Trivial to create a list of dataframes using `group_split` but then I'd like to turn around and make a plot that groups these 5 at a time using facetting.  For reproducibility I'll use `mtcars`

```
ldf <- mtcars %>%
  group_split(carb)
```

Now I'm having a brain lock on how to do the equivalent of:

```
ldf[1:3] %>% 
  bind_rows( .id = "column_label") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = hp)) +
  geom_line()  +
  facet_wrap(carb ~ ., ncol = 1)

ldf[4:6] %>% 
  bind_rows( .id = "column_label") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = hp)) +
  geom_line()  +
  facet_wrap(carb ~ ., ncol = 1)
```

Where I don't have to manually slice the list with [1:3], [4:6] etc. and simply provide an n value like 3 or 5.

Preference for a tidyverse solution second choice base r.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Why split the data in the first place?

Comment: It gets used in a variety of ways so I'm already doing it is the simple truth.

Comment: But if for this particluar case you have a more elegant solution with not splitting it I'm all ears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comments, here's my suggestion without the `group_split`:

```
n_per_group = 3
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    carb_grp = as.integer(factor(carb)),
    plot_grp = (carb_grp - 1) %/% n_per_group
  ) %>%
  group_by(plot_grp) %>%
  group_map(
    ~ggplot(., aes(x = disp, y = hp)) +
       geom_line()  +
       facet_wrap(carb ~ ., ncol = 1)
  )
```

In general, I find most of what I might want to do after `group_split` can be done with `group_map` instead, and there are sometimes advantages to keeping the data together---like ease of regrouping, as in this example.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first look at solutions that do not require splitting then un-splitting ... but if you're stuck with it, then you can group them such as this:

```r
ggs <- split(ldf, (seq_along(ldf)-1) %/% 3) %>%
  lapply(function(z) {
    bind_rows(z, .id = "column_label") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = hp)) +
      geom_line()  +
      facet_wrap(carb ~ ., ncol = 1)
  })
```

(Produces a `list` of 2 `gg` objects.)

Comment: Thank you this fits the bill